# DD of LVM Partition to another disk drive not working - no space left on device

Tags: lvm, dd

I have a vmdk attached to my Linux VM instance (**/dev/sda**).  The disk has 2 partitions, as shown below:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 17.2 GB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a6648

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200    33554431    15727616   8e  Linux LVM
```

I tried to copy both partitions using the dd command to a new hard disk of the same size attached to the VM (**/dev/sdb**).
I created 2 partitions on /dev/sdb using fdisk.  The first partition is the boot partition (/dev/sdb1), and the 2nd partition is for the LVM root partition (dev/sdb2).  I went ahead and ran:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M
```

and that completed without any errors.

Next a ran an lvdisplay to see the logical volumes on /dev/sda:

```
 --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                AQn0bI-7gb7-KjdG-v3ls-yO0I-nkjc-E7bfHP
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2018-10-01 15:06:59 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                1.60 GiB
  Current LE             410
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                rL4g8k-YYXo-0mi1-0Q2U-fNhF-8Izg-f6wd5C
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2018-10-01 15:06:59 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                13.39 GiB
  Current LE             3429
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0
```

I then ran a pvcreate on /dev/sdb2, created a new volume group (**centos-02**), added /dev/sdb2 to the new volume group, then created logical partitions (**root-02**, and **swap-02**) of the exact same size for both the root and swap volumes on /dev/sda2.

I then ran the following dd commands:

```
dd if=/dev/centos/swap of=/dev/centos-02/swap-02
dd if=/dev/centos/root of=/dev/centos-02/root-02
```

the copy from root to root2 fails with this message:

```
dd: writing to ‘/dev/centos-02/root-02’: No space left on device
28082177+0 records in
28082176+0 records out
14378074112 bytes (14 GB) copied, 632.803 s, 22.7 MB/s
```

Can anyone explain why the dd is saying that?  Both logical volumes are exactly the same size, and also, the copy from the old swap volume to new works. Why is the root logical volume copy failing?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Why do you believe the logical volumes are the same size? It's not apparent from your question what the actual sizes are for the newly created LVs.

Comment: I made the lvms the same size on both disks.  I ran an 'lvs' to get the size for the swap and root partitions.

Comment: I don't see this information anywhere in your question. Please add it.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton, but I've resolved my issue. Sorry, if I didn't provide enough information in my post.  I fixed my issue by including the size of the logical extent when creating my logical volumes for both root and swap partitions, and that worked.  So intead of running: 'lvcreate -L 13.39GB -n new_lv new_vg'  I ran 'lvcreate -l 3429 -n new_lv new_vg'.   Then a dd from old lv to new lv worked without errors.